# JQUERY UI draggable div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a dragable div, I want that to be open/close by clicking  **info**  link. I'm using Jquery UI draggable constrain the movement. Here is my [**Fiddle code**](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/2NmsW/5/)

```
<div id="containment-wrapper">
    <div class="draggable ui-widget-content">
        <p id="draggable5" class="ui-widget-header">I'm contained within my parent</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just hide the draggable element on load, and toggle its visibility when clicking on the info link:

```
$("#draggable3").hide().draggable({
    containment: "#containment-wrapper",
    scroll: false
});
$("#draggable5").draggable({
    containment: "parent"
});
$("#showInfo").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#draggable3").toggle();
});
```

Updated <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NmsW/6/)</kbd>

Adding an animation would be as simple as entering the number of milliseconds you would like it to last, inside the `toggle()` function. For example `toggle(500)`.

You can also use other kinds of animations using `fadeToggle()` or `slideToggle()`, also specifying the number of milliseconds as the argument.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NmsW/8/) with a fade animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can give effect on it too like:

```
$("#draggable3").hide().draggable({
    containment: "#containment-wrapper",
    scroll: false
});
$("#draggable5").draggable({
    containment: "parent"
});
$("#showInfo").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#draggable3").is(':visible'))
    $("#draggable3").hide(500);
    else
        $("#draggable3").show(500);
});
```

Comment: can we give some fade in / out animation here?

Comment: @SiddharthShah it might be simpler to use `toggle(500)` or `fadeToggle(500)` in that case.

Comment: @Kiran Yes you can use fedin and fedout

Comment: @chevi i only want to give another way to do it